# binding access database records to html table

Tags: html, ms-access

Can anyone help me with code to bind an access database to html table.I need to get the records from access database and bind it html page.

Regards,
Siva.

Comment: There's no way to do that without some type of programming. If ASP.NET is not an option, I would suggest using classic ASP or PHP, as they're built into the OS.

Comment: James,Can we do it using javascript ?? if so, how? All i need to do is bind the access database records to my html page.

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client (the user's computer), so no. The Access database will reside on the server, and you'll need server-side programming to read the Excel file.

Comment: The good news is, there are probably millions of examples online that you can copy/paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good article that explains how to connect to an Access database and print records using classic ASP. It sounds like you just need something very basic, so ASP is probably a good choice.

http://www.webwiz.co.uk/kb/asp-tutorials/connecting-to-an-access-database.htm